# Why do I need this attribute?

Tags: database-design, relations

This is my relational schema;

```
Book(title, shelfmark, ISBN, author, year)
Genre(name)
GenreBook(name, ISBN)
User(firstName, lastName, cardID)
UserBooks(cardID, ISBN, position)
```

Why do I need the `position` attribute in the last relation? It is a N-M relation but (ISBN, cardID) should be enough to identify a tuple. Maybe my user can have two books with the same ISBN?

Comment: Without knowing what kind of information stored in `position` there's no way to tell why this column exists.

Comment: I have no idea what my prof has suposed to store in `position`, that's why  I'm asking. In description of the reality it's not mentioning any `position` or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `position` is not really part of a relation, but rather an *ordering key* used to denote what book is the user's first, second, third and so on.

Or, like you say, it could be that a user can have multiple copies of a book, but that still wouldn't make `position` part of the *relation*, only of the primary key of `UserBooks`.

Or, a combination of the above two (ordering key and user can have multiple books).